# XML Xpath XSL Return more than one value when node name are the same

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have an XML, with a XSLT I try to extract values. It works, but the expression value-of select in the XSL returns only the first value "Al Pacino". How can I use it to have all the `<Cast>` values?

```
 <Questionario>
  <Video ID="1" Titolo="Scarface">
   <Cast>Al Pacino</Cast>
   <Cast>Steven Bauer</Cast>
   <Cast>Michelle Pfieffer</Cast>
   <Genere>azione e avventura</Genere>
    <Sottogenere>crime action</Sottogenere>
    <Sottogenere>Thriller</Sottogenere>
    <Sottogenere>Gangster</Sottogenere>
```

XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Report Questionari Slow TV</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>Video Visionati</h3>
            <div>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//Video"> 
                </xsl:apply-templates>

            </div>


        <xsl:for-each select="Questionario/Video">

                <xsl:value-of select="@Titolo"/>

                 <xsl:value-of select="Cast"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing this to output the `Cast`

```
<xsl:value-of select="Cast"/>
```

In XSLT 1.0 this will only select the first `Cast` element, but you have multiple ones. Try using `xsl:for-each` instead

```
<xsl:for-each select="Cast">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
     <br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively you could use templates.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Cast" />
```

You would then need a template to match this

```
<xsl:template match="Cast">
     <xsl:value-of select="." />
     <br />
</xsl:template>
```